# cloning github to google colab didn't clone the newest file

Tags: github, google-colaboratory, git-clone

I tried to clone my github repo to colab. When I try to run my code its fine but didn't update the newest files I've added to my github

The files:

[image: the files]

The result after run my code still like 3-4 months ago, the 'dataset_after_preprocessing.csv' and 'stopword-id.txt' didn't come up

Result after I added my new file:

[image: result after I added my new file]

Here's my code

[image: code]

I expect the code I run is running well, and the newest file come up in my colab.

Comment: When you clone a repo, you get the default branch (usually `master` or `main`).  Are the missing files in that branch, or a different branch?

Answer (score 0):

The git clone is failing because the folder in Colab is already there.

Delete it locally first like this...

```
!rm -r TA/
!git clone https://github.com/keenan09/TA.git
```